# Should compounds in a generic reaction be italicised (typography)?

Tags: notation

As of recent, I provided an [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/69006/27806) to the question [Law of mass action & collision theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68195/27806). Therein I wrote a generic reaction

$$\ce{$r_1$R1 + $r_2$R2 + \ldots + $r_n$R_n <=> $p_1$P1 + $p_2$P2 + \ldots + $p_m$P_m}.\tag{1}$$

It seemed natural to write stoichiometric coefficents in Italic, and use upright Roman for the species themselves.

- Italic would be in line with the fact that the coefficients are numbers, and vary with reactions (are different for different transitions).
- Upright Roman is how we usually write chemical species, *e.g.,* $\ce{NaCl}$.

Though if I were to overthink, the $\ce{R_$i$}$ would also seem to be *variables* as such. Since this is a generic reaction, $\ce{R_$i$} \in \{\mathrm{every\ imaginable \ chemical \ species}\}$. Using this logic, I ought to write $(1)$ instead as

$$r_1R_1 + r_2R_2 + \ldots + r_nR_n \ce{<=>} p_1P_1 + p_2P_2 + \ldots + p_mP_m.\tag{1'}$$

---

- **Is there an official example or guideline how to handle this situation?**

Personally I wholeheartedly support option $(1)$ but is this what is recommended?

- **What about the subindices? Upright or Italic?**

Note that this qualitatively differs from [Proper typography of “$\ce{NO_x}$”](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20315/27806). There the number of elements actually changes within a chemical species (marks the number of carbons in alkanes for example) whereas here it is more for labelling purposes.

Comment: Since Chem.SE is going through $18$th-turn-$19$th century Vienna in terms of typography expertise, this is probably the best time to ask such a question.

Comment: I'd agree with "It seemed natural to write stoichiometric coefficents in Italic, and use upright Roman for the species themselves." Not sure if ACS style guide would agree or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the basic rule of a variable (that can hold multiple values) being italic, I would go for the $r_nR_n$ style (4 times italics), but then I found the following in the [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf) (printed page 53):

> $$0 = \sum_j \nu_j \mathrm{B}_j \quad \text{where }\mathrm{B}_j\text{ denotes a species in the reaction ...}$$

Here, the B is upright although it is definitely a placeholder. I don't understand, why.

For the subindices, I think (hope) there is no doubt that the $n$ and $m$ should be italic, because they clearly are variables standing for numbers (either any number as in the sum, or for an unknown maximum number $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ as in the generic reaction). Both form are well established in mathematics (and I hope chemists don't deviate).

---

The [IUPAC Gold Book, R05156](https://www.iupac.org/goldbook/R05156.pdf) uses the same convention.

> For the general chemical reaction :
>   $$a\,\mathrm{A} + b\,\mathrm{B} \rightarrow p\,\mathrm{P} + q\,\mathrm{Q} + \dots% not using \ce to have proper formating regardless of mhchem version$$

And they do not mean Boron and Phosphorus.

(Spotted via [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/63437/24052)).

Comment: Great find! Luckily it is a recommendation I prefer, so that's nice. (regardless of whether it follows the variable/label rule)

Comment: Added 2nd source

Comment: If it helps your understanding, simply regard those as contractions or abbreviations. For example when we write a simplified formula for acetic acid, we may write $\ce{AcOH}$. We might abbreviate an aryl-moiety simply with $\ce{Ar\bond{-}}$, or any moiety with $\ce{R\bond{-}}$. I think in this particular case it is better to use upright characters to signify that these are chemical species. But this is just me guessing here...